# How to unset subdomain with route url helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a redirect (to login_url => /login) in an admin namespace/subdomain that I want to go back up to the (so domain.com/login rather than admin.domain.com/login). It seems like things like login_path(subdomain: '') or login_path(subdomain: nil) etc either break or just don't achieve the desired result.

My current work around is to just do login_path(subdomain: 'www'), but I'd really rather just drop the subdomain entirely. Is this possible out of the box? Or should I just rework the helpers?

edit: 
It seems like the best solution here is something like:

`login_url(host: request.domain)`

I think login_path(subdomain: '') should simply strip off any subdomain(s), since it's result (.domain.com, with that leading dot) is really never going to be the desired result.

Comment: I ran into this too. It seems odd that specifying a subdomain of `''` or `nil` returns `.example.com`. Thanks for updating your question with the solution. Maybe you should just add it as an answer and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to implement something like this: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3